# RDoc template customization

Tags: ruby, rdoc

how can I change my default RDoc template for my gem environment.

I'd like my gem server to look like this RDoc: http://getcloudkit.com/api/ and I've seen that design around so this shouldn't be so difficult.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you like to have a RDoc template like http://getcloudkit.com/api/ you need to install and use Hanna by Mislav Marohnić to generate your docs. check it out here: http://github.com/mislav/hanna